# reactjs props VS state: not setting state right

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add infinite scroll with a loop that renders posts.
However, I kept getting the following error that my obj is undefined. Does anyone know what went wrong?

Original ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at Object.fetchMoreData [as next] (bundle.js:27529)
    at InfiniteScroll.onScrollListener (bundle.js:27932)
    at InfiniteScroll.<anonymous> (bundle.js:28093)
fetchMoreData @ bundle.js:27529
onScrollListener @ bundle.js:27932
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:28093
```

After I added bind fetchMoreData() in the constructor, the original error is gone. But I suspect that my state data is still not set properly as I a getting the following error. I tried to log console but nothing is showing...

```
bundle.js:27530 GET http://localhost:8000/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)
fetchMoreData @ bundle.js:27530
onScrollListener @ bundle.js:27935
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:28096
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

the api is as follows. Here I am keeping track of the api url of the next things I should show on the page if the infinite scroll is triggered.

```
{
  "next": "/api/v1/p/?size=1&page=2", 
  "results": [
    {
      "postid": 2, 
      "url": "/api/v1/p/2/"
    }
  ], 
  "url": "/api/v1/p/"
}
```

my code is as follows.  I tried both state and props in the fetchMoreData() but neither worked.

```
  constructor(props) {
    // Initialize mutable state
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [], next: "", url: ""};
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    // Call REST API to get number of likes
    fetch(this.props.url, { credentials: 'same-origin' })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        results: data.results,
        next: data.next,
        url: data.url,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  fetchMoreData() {

    fetch(this.props.next, {method: 'GET'})
    .then((response)=>{
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data)=>{
      this.setState({
        results: this.state.results.concat(data.results),
        next: data.next,
      });
    });

  }

  render() {
    let has_more;
    if( this.state.next == '' ){
      has_more = false;
    } else {
      has_more = true;
    }


    return (
      <InfiniteScroll next={this.fetchMoreData} hasMore={has_more}>

      <ul> 
        {this.state.results.map((post)=> (
          <li><Post url={post.url}/></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      </InfiniteScroll>


    );
  }
```

Comment: looks like a problem with `this`.  Try `bind` it.

Comment: `next={this.fetchMoreData.bind(this)}`

Comment: in `fetchMoreData` use `this.state.next` instead of `this.props.next`

Comment: great! I'll post an answer so you can accept

Comment: Also --my infinite scrolling is valid only for once even though I update the 'next' in setState() to data.next . Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: are you sure you get correct data in `data.next`?

Comment: hey I am pretty sure that my api is right... but I am not sure data.next is getting the right data. I tried console log but it is not showing anything. How can I check if data.next is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using a class you need to bind your function so it has the correct `this`:

```
next={this.fetchMoreData.bind(this)}
```

Then, in `fetchMoreData` use `this.state.next` instead of `this.props.next`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fetchMoreData = () => {

    fetch(this.props.next, {method: 'GET'})
    .then((response)=>{
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data)=>{
      this.setState({
        results: this.state.results.concat(data.results),
        next: data.next,
      });
    });
```

When adding the arrow function your `this` will point to the current class and you'll be able to access `props` and `state`